# $E \subset [0,1]$, $m(E \cap I) \ge \alpha m(I)$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and all intervals $I$, then $m(E) = 1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Currently, I'm solving exercise 7 of chapter 3 in Stein's Real Analysis.

[image]

For reference, the Corollary 1.5 of chapter 3 is as follows:

**Corollary 1.5** Suppose E is a measurable set in $\mathbb R^d$. Then,

(i) almost every $x \in E$ is a point of density of $E$

(ii) almost every $x \notin E$ is not a point of density of $E$

And, $x$ is a point of **Lebesgue density** of $E$ if $\lim_{m(B) \to 0;x\in B}\frac{m(B \cap E}{m(B)} = 1$

.....................

I started this problem with defining $F = [0,1] - E$ which is measurable.

My goal is to show that $m(F) = 0$ and thus $m(E) = 1$.

Since $E \cap F = \phi$, $(I \cap E) \cap (I \cap F) = \phi$.

$E \cup F = [0,1]$ leads to $I = (I \cap E) \cup (I \cap F)$

Then, $(I \cap F) = I - (I \cap E)$ and $m(I \cap F) = m(I) - m(I \cap E) \le (1-\alpha)m(I)$

So, $\frac{m(I \cap F)}{m(I)} \le 1-\alpha$ and this holds for all intervals $I \subset [0,1]$

This leads to $\lim_{m(I) \to 0; x \in I}\frac{m(I \cap F)}{m(I)} \le 1-\alpha$.

(It is trivial that $0 < \alpha < 1)$

///

This is what I've done and I've found it difficult to connect this result to $m(F) = 0$.

Any comments about my trial or other better approaches would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Use Lebesgue density theorem.

Comment: You can also prove this using the approximation theorem (Ref. Halmos).

Comment: The book has no explanation about Lebesgue density thm (I guess), so could you explain more in detail about how to use the thm to conclude it? Or, is there other ways to use the Cor 1.5 above to finish the proof (as mentioned in the exercise)?

Comment: Approximatin theorem from Halmos' book gives  a more elementary proof. You can approximate $E$ by a finite union of intervals.

Comment: The result is almost immediate from the corollary.  I don't where your difficulty is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially observe that $ E $ has positive measure. Then use Lebesgue's differentiation theorem to obtain that $ \mathrm{1}_E \geq \alpha  $ pointwise almost everywhere in $[0,1] $. Now if $ m(E)<1 $ we would have $ m([0,1] \setminus E )>0. $  But then we could find $ x \in [0,1] $ so that $ x \not \in E $ and $ \mathrm{1}_E(x) \geq \alpha $ which implies that $ \alpha  \leq 0 $ which cannot happen from premise of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The limit you proved shows $x$ is not a point of density of $F$.  That is, $F$ has no points of density.  So apply (i) to $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $F= [0,1] \backslash E$. Assume that $\beta \colon= \mu(F) > 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We have $(1+\epsilon) \beta > \beta$. There exists (by the definition of (exterior) measure)  a countable family of intervals $(I_n)$ such that $\cup_n I_n \supset F$ and $\sum \mu(I_n) < (1+\epsilon) \beta$. We get
$$ \sum \mu(I_n) < (1+\epsilon) \beta = (1+\epsilon) \mu(F)\le (1+\epsilon) \sum \mu(F\cap I_n)$$
and so, for at least one of the $I_n$'s we have
$$\mu(I_n) \le (1+\epsilon) \mu(F\cap I_n)$$